# Prove that $X=\{(x,y): y=mx+c\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Prove that $X=\{(x,y): y=mx+c\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

I've taken the hint from [Prove that $X= \{ (x,y): y = mx + c \}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848150/prove-that-x-x-y-y-mx-c-is-homeomorphic-to-mathbb-r)

So, my function is $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow X, f(x)=(x,mx+c)$

I have proved this is one-one and onto.

Now I need to prove that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ maps open sets into open sets.

Here is where I'm stuck: what do open sets look like in the relative topology on $X$?

**EDIT:** Expanding on the hint given:

Let $H$ be an open set in the topology on $X$.

Then $H=X\cap G$ where $G$ is an open set on the standard topology on $\mathbb{R^2}$

So, $H=X\cap [\cup \{(a,b) \times (c',d) \}]$, using the base of standard topology on $\mathbb{R^2}$

So, $f^{-1}(H)=f^{-1}(X) \cap f^{-1} [\cup \{(a,b) \times (c',d) \}]$, using the bijection of $f$,

i.e. $f^{-1}(H)=f^{-1}(X) \cap [\cup f^{-1} \{(a,b) \times (c',d) \}]$

i.e. $f^{-1}(H)=\mathbb{R} \cap [\cup f^{-1} \{(a,b) \times (c',d) \}]$

Now, I think $f^{-1} (a,b) \times (c,d)$ will be $(a,c')$ such that$ b=ax+c,d=c'x+c$. Am I correct?

Comment: Recall that the open sets in $X$ are intersecctions between open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (open balls) and $X$ (assuming that $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$).

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to give a specific inverse, here we have
$f^{-1} ((x,y)) = x$, where $(x,y) \in X$.

This function is continuous of all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ hence it is continuous on the restriction to $X$.